# Magento 2 remove the unwanted sidebar div displaying something I don't know where come from

Tags: magento2, sidebar

the image attached shows the sidebar in a category page that lists all its products with this sidebar that shows search block and compare block then this div that shows that error. I don't know how this been generated but I want to remove this error info div
[additional sidebar div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZTT9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn on path hints
2. Get file template
3. Copy template to your theme and remove your div.